# Ubuntu 20.04 Starts using Nvidia GPU when logging in when I want to use integrated graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, battery, intel, msi

I have recently moved to Ubuntu for the laptop (MSI) and found out that Ubuntu is forcing the computer to use the Nvidia graphics card, while I am trying to use the integrated graphics from the Intel CPU to reduce battery draining.
I have already tried to use the proprietary drivers from Nvidia with the software (Nvidia X Server) to choose to use the integrated graphics, but with no use. I have found that until I log in to my account, the laptop will use the intel graphics, but as soon I log in, the Nvidia card will kick-in until I turn off my computer.

Does anyone how to fix this? I would like to keep using Ubuntu for university.

EDIT: Hello, I decided to reinstall Ubuntu as I fixed momentarely, but still getting the use of gpu; after that, all went well, now was getting 2,5h of battery, more than before, so I decided to reinstall Slimbook Battery Saver, as soon I selected the battery saver option, the use of GPU has started again and the laptop won't stop using it, even if I change the setting to de optimum; I will report this bug to them.

Comment: Open Nvidia X Server Settings, select the profile you want (Intel) and shutdown.

Comment: Sorry, this is what I meant by using the software, it doesn't change anything, it still uses the Nvidia graphics card.

Comment: So you're saying that after selecting the IGPU profile and shutting down, the next usage you find Nvidia selected again? If not then how exactly are you concluding you're using Nvidia? If so then please check UEFI settings as some firmwares allow selecting between integrated/discrete/on-demand and that setting takes precedence, of course.

Comment: Yes and no, Nvidia X Server says that the profile selected is the one using the intel graphics, but in my laptop there is a light on the power button that if it is using the Nvidia card is orange (like now), if using the intel it is white, also the gpu fans are being used all the time; I will seek how to change the settings in UEFI, thanks

Comment: You can open system settings > about and confirm. What you see there is the actual graphics being used. Whatever you say about the "hardware signs" likely aren't as meaningful as you might think (and probably depend on proprietary drivers/software available only for Windows).

Comment: Okey, so it says that it is using the MESA Intel UHD graphics, so then it should be using the intel gpu, then I have to find other things that are  draining the battery, thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Of note: Fans are mostly controlled by the firmware. If yours isn't managing them as expected that is a problem with said firmware (or a design/engineering decision). An UEFI update may or may not address the issue.